# How to highlight a cell when formula result from another sheet changes?

Tags: vba, excel

This is one that's been killing me and I've tried almost every solution on the Internet.

Here's background. I have an HR model that has each department broken out on separate tabs. I want to run an extract from our payroll system each payroll run and send highlight any updates individually. If someone's title or salary or status changes, I want to have that called out by highlighting the cell.

Each tab uses an INDEX/MATCH lookup to the extract tab to pull in the current information. What I want is if any value changes or is new(new hire, for example), highlight the cells.

I've played with Worksheet_Calculate and Worksheet_Change to no avail. Worksheet_Change doesn't fire because I'm not making the change directly on the sheet and Worksheet_Calculate doesn't have the Target object for to reference. I've tried the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim updatedCell As Range
Set updatedCell = Range(Target.Dependents.Address)

If Not Intersect(updatedCell, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
   updatedCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

End Sub
```

The range I actually need evaluated is A7:R104 but I've been trying to get anything to work when linked to another sheet.

This works fine if formula of target cell is pointing to another cell on same sheet. The moment you point to one on another sheet it doesn't work. I've tried most of the solutions on here with no success. I've even tried putting the Worksheet_Change on the extract sheet and see if I can trigger it that way with no luck.

Is there a recommended solution to triggering a change to a cell for a formula linked to another sheet?

Comment: You do not explain how data is changing.  I assume your workbook holds the data from the last payroll run.  You then get data from the new payroll run.  Does that new data overwrite the old data?  Do you want the new value of a formula in a department tag to trigger a colour change?  How can there be an existing formula for a new hire?  What about leavers?  I have difficulty in imagining how this could work without a VBA comparison of this month's data against last.

Comment: Thanks Tony, you are right. I'll have current snapshot of payroll data on a tab, and the worksheet that I need to detect a change has index/match formulas to pull all the data in. The formulas strictly pull in whatever is on the ADP tab depending on cost center which will be flexed per tab. So this accounts for any terminations, any transfers, etc. Works beautifully just can't detect changes

Comment: See if I have this correct.  Sheet1 is the previous payroll.  Sheet2 is the latest payroll.  Sheet3 onwards are departmental sheets that import all data relevant to each department from Sheet2.  You want Sheets3 onwards to be coloured if the values in Sheet1 and Sheet2 differ.  I am not an Excel user; I just use VBA as a convenient programming language and workbooks as a convenient repositary for simple data.  What you seek sounds easy with VBA but I have no idea how to achieve it with formulae or conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

so I just saw this post, I don't know if you've found the solution or are still looking, but:

if you select a cell in sheet 3, you can then go to the home tab, go to "conditional formatting" -highlight cell rules - more rules (at the bottom) - and "use formulas to determine which cells to format" and then put your cursor in the formula box. now, select a cell in sheet 1 (click the sheet1 tab, and click a cell) and you'll notice it should populate the address for sheet1, and the cell u selected. now type <> after that cells address, then select sheet2 and a cell. then click format, and choose a fill color. then ok. if you go to conditional formatting and manage rules it will show there the rule / formula and which cells it applies to.

doing this i was able to select cell D10 in sheet 3, and make it an ugly green if cells in sheet1 and 2 didnt match (I picked which cells) you can also select a range of cells.

thusly, you can apply this rule to whatever dells you want, and if you record a macro of you setting this conditional formatting, you can manitpulate that macro to apply it to a bunch of different cells, and change the ranges. (using loops / variables)